# A ListView wider than screen

Tags: android, listview

I want to achieve this:

[image: ListView wider than screen]

Explanation:

The ListView item consists of several TextView next to each other. Each TextView uses a certain weight of the total weight.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:text="Tv 1" />

    <TextView
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:text="Tv 2" />

    <TextView
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:text="Tv 3" />
```

They are too many TextViews and what I'm currently getting is this:

[image: Textviews in linearLayout]

I want to be able to scroll horizontally and vertically to see the content of the ListView

This is my current Activity that holds the ListView:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="....">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFetchItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fetch items" />
```

Comment: You should look at `RecyclerView` and `NestedScrollview`. Also you wouldnt want your LinearLayout width to match parent because that is going to be the width of your screen in this case

Answer (score 0):

Lets try to put everything into [HorizontalScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView):

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" >
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="....">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFetchItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fetch items" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```